# ComboBox not filling with code

Tags: vb.net

I have the following code:

```
Using conn = New SqlConnection(connStr)
        Dim sql = "SELECT [CATEGORIA], [AREA] FROM [CATEGORIAS] WHERE ([AREA] = @AREA)"
        Dim sqlCmd = New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AREA", CStr(PublicLogin.Area))

        conn.Open()
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn)
        da.Fill(ds, "CATEGORIAS")

        With cboCat
            .DataSource = ds.Tables("CATEGORIAS")
            .DisplayMember = "CATEGORIAS_AREA"
            .ValueMember = "CATEGORIAS_AREA"
            .SelectedIndex = 0
        End With

    End Using
```

It should in theory fill the combo box right? It doesn't. It doesn't give me any errors or anything; the combo box just sits there empty. I am pretty sure the query is working well and its grabbing the correct info but the Combobox doesn't fill. If I take the where query out it fills the CB with 'System.Data.Row...'

UPDATE: Working code in case someone needs it;

```
        Using conn = New SqlConnection(connStr)
        Dim sql = "SELECT [CATEGORIA], [AREA] FROM [CATEGORIAS] WHERE ([AREA] = @AREA)"
        Dim sqlCmd = New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AREA", CStr(PublicLogin.Area))

        conn.Open()
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd)
        da.Fill(ds, "CATEGORIAS")

        With cboCat
            .DataSource = ds.Tables("CATEGORIAS")
            .DisplayMember = "CATEGORIA"
            .ValueMember = "CATEGORIA"
            .SelectedIndex = 0
        End With

    End Using
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its empty because probably the query returns nothing. Notice that you are not adding the parameter to the final query on the `sql` variable.

You create a command with the query and the parameter but you never use it, so when you select all the values `WHERE ([AREA] = @AREA)` it returns nothing.

Try this:

```
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd)
```

Comment: +1. I did not notice `sqlCmd` is not being used, before your answer. Now I am puzzled how it does not throw an exception...

Comment: You were right. I took the WHERE part of the query out and its displaying the data now (thanks to Neolisk's answer). I checked a breakpoint on the parameter and the Variable PublicLogin.Area is passing correctly the value. I didn't fully understand your initial sentence though... the parameter is in the query (@AREA) or is there something obvious that I am missing? (happens to me a lot).

Comment: I am never calling the actual sqlCMD. Goddangit. Where should I add it correctly?

Comment: Hmm this is weird. I updated the code now but it still won't load. I am sure that I can try the direct query as SysDragon posted it and I could use it perfectly since the variable I am calling comes from a fixed DropDown so it will never overload or cause an injection attack. Decisions... I updated the code.

Answer (score 2):

This looks odd to me:

```
.DisplayMember = "CATEGORIAS_AREA"
.ValueMember = "CATEGORIAS_AREA"
```

It should probably be something like this:

```
.DisplayMember = "CATEGORIA"
.ValueMember = "AREA"
```

From [MSDN on DisplayMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.displaymember.aspx):

> Gets or sets a string that specifies the property or **column** from which to retrieve strings for display in the combo boxes.

**EDIT:** You also need to replace [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kx703tc9.aspx):

```
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn)
```

with [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awzk4kc1.aspx):

```
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd)
```

Otherwise your parameters are never used.

Comment: Tried it. CB still empty. I played around with it a bit and still no go.

Comment: @LordRelix: Did you verify that `s.Tables("CATEGORIAS")` has any data?

Comment: I did what SysDragon told me below and your solution worked. its bringing the data correctly. Now why the heck isn't the WHERE working....

Comment: SO should allow for double answering. Both your answers work in my case =/

Comment: @LordRelix: That's what upvotes are for. I have no problem with you accepting SysDragon's answer in this case. He was the first to point at unused `sqlCmd`.